# How to fix the navbar toggle button not displaying items in Bootstrap 5.2

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-5

I have bootstrap 5.2.3 installed as an npm dependency in my angular application.

I am trying to add a toggle button in my navbar to display a list of list items when the page size is reduced.

```
<nav id="nav"
     aria-label="Header"
     class="navbar navbar-expand-lg mb-3">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand">
      <em class="fa-solid fa-toolbox">
      </em>&nbsp;
      <span>App Name</span>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="navbarSupportedContent"
         aria-label="Menu Navigation"
         class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" role="tablist">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let app of appList">
          <li role="presentation"
              class='nav-item'
              routerLinkActive="active"
              [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
            <a class="nav-link"
               [routerLink]="app.routerLink"
               (click)="selectApp(app.id)">
              {{app.name}}
            </a>
          </li>
        </ng-container>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="row mt-2">
  <div class="col">
    <div *ngIf="notify" class="alert alert-success notification">
      {{ notify }}
    </div>
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I have consulted Bootstrap's official [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/) and tried to reverse-engineer my code using their template but the application refuses to display the list of items.

The only time it displays it is when I set my `.navbar-toggler` element's class to `.show` but this keeps the list open by default.

Comment: Use [this library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap)

Comment: Thanks, I pulled the repo and tested it in the browser. It works as it should. Do you know why using bootstrap with angular sometimes does not work?

Comment: Well you need the bootstrap css styles,  but you need the javascript too. You could try and add the bootstrap.js to the angular.json, but this would have several implications. First of all, the bootstrap javascript wouldn't be tree-shakable, and all will be included in the main bundle. Secondly, I read that this javascript wouldn't be working as it should anyway, because the js must be initialized after corresponding html elements are rendered. So implementing this stuff the angular way is a good way forward

Comment: There are other ng-bootstrap libraries out there, but these only deal with implementing the javascript code the angular way. All styles are still bundled in the main bundle with these other libs, even when you don't need them on initial load. I've attempted (pretty much successfully) to also extract these component styles into the angular components, which trims off another 160 kb from the main bundle.

Comment: At the moment I'm working on making the components work when `noscript` is enabled, but that's another challenge

Comment: Also, the library makes use of the [`@angular/cdk/overlay`](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/main/src%2Fcdk%2Foverlay) which ensures that overlay elements are not being cut off by relative-positioned parent elements. In most components, I'm able to include the `overlay-prebuilt.css` automatically, but we cannot do so for directives. In these rare cases you need to include the `<bs-has-overlay>` component too. But just look at the examples/code in the demo application, atm they explain how to use the components